# Resolving IP to hostname in Python 2

Tags: python, file, networking, ip-address

This piece of script will take one argument (file which contain list of ip, one per line) and convert it to its hostname. For now this will only work with IPv4.

This definitely doesn't look good and I want experts to review it and suggest some good ways of coding it in Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import sys

BLUE='\033[34m'
RED='\033[31m'
NORMAL='\033[0m'

def check_ip():
        try:
                socket.inet_aton(ip)
        except Exception, e:
                print RED+"Invalid ip addresss = "+NORMAL + str(ip)

file = sys.argv[1]
with open(file) as ipfile:
        for iplist in ipfile:
                for IP in iplist.split():
                        ip = IP.strip(' \t\n\r')
                        if ip == '':
                                pass
                        else:
                                check_ip()
                                host = socket.getfqdn(ip)
                                print BLUE+ip+NORMAL + " hostname is " + BLUE+host+NORMAL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard indentation in Python is 4 spaces, as specified in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).  This is a pretty strong convention, since Python is very sensitive to indentation.

To process a file specified on the command line, use the [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module.  It supports multiple filenames, and it also falls back to reading standard input if there is no filename given.

Instead of `for iplist in ipfile`, I would say `for line in ipfile` — because it's not a list until you have split it.  It's also odd that you wrote the code to expect a "list", when in your question, you specified one IP address per line.

[`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), with no separator specified, splits on whitespace and automatically discards whitespace from the results for you.

Calling `check_ip()` with the `ip` as a global variable is bad practice.  You should pass it as a parameter.  However, I wouldn't bother defining a function for it, especially since that function has a side-effect of printing its output.

The `except Exception, e` syntax is [obsolescent](//stackoverflow.com/a/2535770/1157100).  Prefer writing `except Exception as e`.  (In this case, you don't need to name the exception at all.)

Since all of the color-changing codes should reset the color back to normal, I would define a function for that.

```
import fileinput
import socket

RED = '31'
BLUE = '34'

def color(color_code, text):
    return '\033[{}m{}\033[0m'.format(color_code, text)

for line in fileinput.input():
    for ip in line.split():
        try:
            socket.inet_aton(ip)
        except Exception as invalid_ip:
            print color(RED, 'Invalid IP address = ') + ip
        else:
            hostname = socket.getfqdn(ip)
            print color(BLUE, ip) + ' hostname is ' + color(BLUE, hostname)
```

Comment: Thank for review. I have tried your code and it works great. I would accept your answer. what about using def main() function as default one? Isn't that more professional?

Comment: Yes, `def main()` would be better practice, but sometimes I prefer to avoid adding three lines of boilerplate code for such a trivial program.

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your code that I don't see how it works as is. I don't think you need a "check_ip" function but in this case it would be more useful for a "print_hostname" instead that took a single argument for an ip address and printed it.

But here are some notes what I see right now.

**check_ip**
Doesn't take an argument so it should error when called because "socket.inet_aton(ip)" doesn't have ip defined anywhere. Also if it does raise an exception, it won't stop your script from running and print more than just your "Invalid ip address " message. It would continue to try to print the host name line.

This is what I would do:

```
def print_hostname(ip):
    try:
        socket.inet_aton(ip)
    except socket.error:
        print RED + "Invalid IP address = " + NORMAL + ip
    else:
        hostname = socket.getfqdn(ip)
        print BLUE + ip + NORMAL + " hostname is " + BLUE + hostname + NORMAL

file = sys.argv[1]
with open(file) as ipFile:
    for ipLine in ipFile:
        ip = ipLine.strip()
        if ip: # just in case there was a blank line
            print_hostname(ip)
```

Comment: Thanks for review. I have check your code too. I have listed two ip in same line separate with space but it only resolves first ip and ignore second ip. But first answer address that too.

Comment: Glad you found an answer. In your post it said one ip per line so that is what I assumed.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I mentioned one ip per line and your scripts works fine too. But first answer can handle more than I expected.